# Java + Lombok - populate a field at .build() time

Tags: java, lombok

The idea is to have `summary` being populated at `.build()` time.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Book
{
    protected String title;
    protected String author;
    protected String description;
}
```

---

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class BookSummary extends Book
{
    public String summary;

    public BookSummary(BookSummaryBuilder<?, ?> b)
    {
       super(b);
       this.summary = getTitle() + getAuthor() + getDescription();
    }  
}
```

Everything works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler/more elegant way to do the same without the need of creating this constructor

**UPDATE**

I cannot simply override the summary get method because some APIs that will receive this object as parameter don't use the accessors to retrieve the values from fields.

For example:

```
public class BookSummary extends Book
{
    @Builder.Default
    public String summary = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    public String getSummary()
    {
        return getTitle() + getAuthor() + getDescription();
    }
}

BookSummary bookSummary = BookSummary.builder()
            .title("Java forever")
            .author("John John")
            .description("bla-bla-bla-bla")
            .build();

String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(bookSummary)
```

---

JSON:

```
{
    "summary":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "title":"Java forever",
    "author":"John John",
    "description":"bla-bla-bla-bla"
}
```

Comment: It works fine without that constructor, did you test it ?

Comment: Create `getSummary` method and in there,  `this.summary = getTitle() + getAuthor() + getDescription();`

Comment: @YoucefLAIDANI - in which moment summary would be populated without the constructor?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - I updated the post to explain why create a getSummary will not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

There is no simpler way to do this directly, however, this design is dubious. Given that there is a separate field, it is now possible to have 'invalid' state - where the fields do not agree. For example, where `summary` simply contains "Hello world" instead of what you actually want it to contain.

A better solution is to not have a field at all, and just write a getter:

```
public String getSummary() {
  return getTitle() + " " + getAuthor() + " " + getDescription();
}
```

Alternatively, if the design of this class (your question isn't clear on this topic) is such that you *can* add a summary, but if you don't, you get the title+author+description, still, write the getter, just, a slightly different take: Use `null` or `""` as sentinel:

```
public String getSummary() {
  return summary != null ? summary :
    (getTitle() + " " + getAuthor() + " " getDescription());
}
```

Both of these strategies obviate the need to explicitly set the field as part of your build process. Lombok does have the `@Builder.Default` mechanism, but this mechanism cannot be used to reference anything set during the build process (i.e. you can set as default 'Hello world', or even `"" + System.currentTimeMillis()` if you want, any java expression will do, but you cannot refer to the title, author, or description set by the caller to the builder, so you couldn't use it to 'default' the `summary` field to what you want.

Comment: I've updated the post to explain why create a getSummary() will not work in my case. This field will never be set explicitly, just by the builder at build time.

Comment: You can generally configure GSON and friends to call a getter instead.